How does CMake's universal binary builds work?
When CMake builds for both architecutres (Intel and Apple Silicon).
Does it build for the architecutres separately and join them using tools like lipo or does it optimize the builds to make minmum compilations to build for both architectures?

You can build in verbose mode and look at the compiler commands.

it just adds proper compilation/linking flags to build process. -arch x86_64 -arch arm64

I think it's neither, but anyway you have to make sure everything else you give the compiler like included headers and sysroot are going to work for both architectures. Are you obtaining any programming error messages?

I didn't even know it could build Universal; I have been building the arch's separately and combining the binaries and .dSYM using a script.  I might to re-think that...
